# How to make <CFWDDX action="CFML2WDDX"...> generate numbers without ‘.0’ in the end?

Tags: coldfusion, wddx

I am using ColdFusion MX 7. 
When I use  to convert a structure into WDDX, all numbers that are in fact INTEGER become DOUBLE ones in output WDDX. In other words, "1" in structure becomes 1.0 in the WDDX.

Can I somehow avoid this - to have just 1 instead of 1.0 in the output WDDX?